# nginx does not respond requests for rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, nginx, amazon-ec2, passenger

I try to deploy my app to EC2 son Amazon via nginx and passenger. I did what the passenger installation comments say. But when I run my nginx and try to enter my site it does not respond even withan error message. It loops forever. I looked the pstree output for my non-workign nginx:

```
init─┬─PassengerWatchd─┬─PassengerHelper─┬─ruby─┬─ruby─┬─ruby─┬─ruby───{ruby}
     │                 │                 │      │      │      └─{ruby}
     │                 │                 │      │      └─{ruby}
     │                 │                 │      └─2*[{ruby}]
     │                 │                 └─27*[{PassengerHelper}]
     │                 ├─PassengerLoggin───{PassengerLoggin}
     │                 └─3*[{PassengerWatchd}]
     ├─acpid
     ├─atd
     ├─avahi-daemon───avahi-daemon
     ├─cron
     ├─dbus-daemon
     ├─dhclient3
     ├─6*[getty]
     ├─mysqld───17*[{mysqld}]
     ├─nginx───nginx
     ├─rsyslogd───3*[{rsyslogd}]
     ├─sshd───sshd───sshd───bash───pstree
     ├─udevd───2*[udevd]
     ├─upstart-socket-
     ├─upstart-udev-br
     └─whoopsie───{whoopsie}
```

also I have nginx in my laptop and it is working fine and it gives this pstree output (partially)just after it is got an request:

```
├─PassengerWatchd─┬─PassengerHelper─┬─ruby
     │                 │                 └─27*[{PassengerHelper}]
     │                 ├─PassengerLoggin───{PassengerLoggin}
     │                 └─3*[{PassengerWatchd}]
```

I see that there are some zombie processes on my EC2 instance after an request:

What you think about the problem and any suggestion to solve it?

After a wait it gives Gateway Timeout 504